# SVG external reference without id

Tags: html, svg

I have a simple SVG file with the contents like this `(icon.svg)`:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
    <path d="..."/>
</svg>
```

How can I make an external reference for it without adding an `id` attribute? Something like:

```html
<svg>
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="icon.svg"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: You can't. You'll need to add an id.

Comment: If you want to load the entire file you could load it via an <image>.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple, For a normal svg on the page use:

```
<img src="/path/to/svg" width="" height="">
```

for site icon use:

```
<link rel="icon" href="/path/to/svg">
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party....If you want to have an external reference to a svg without id, you can utilize HTML's `<object>`

Example usage:

```
<object data="pathToSome.svg" width="20" height="20"> </object>
```

Comment: this way, it's possible change attributes of the icon?
for example, style="fill:currentColor;"

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as regular image like that:
`<img src="example.svg">`
or:
`<link rel="icon" href="example.svg">`

Answer (score -4):

Since svg are often small file size -especially a tiny icon- I always host them locally in my img folder. A favicon [for browser tab] I put in the same folder as index.html. It just makes it easier to host your own svg on your server space and also prevents anything from breaking if the external host goes offline or takes down that file. ☺ Hope this helps.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question

Comment: @Inc33, I assume what they meant is that they should download the icon and add it to their own repository, which would allow them to add an `id` attribute. Either way, the answer is not well laid and should either be deleted or rewritten to make this point clear